# React Native updating data onState variable change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

i am trying to execute a function that update the Users data whenever the user come at the end of the Array like so :

```
  componentDidUpdate = () => {
  if (this.state.isLoading == false && this.state.Users.length == this.state.currentIndex) {
    this.loadUsers()
  }
}
```

Here is the loadUsers() function

```
  loadUsers = () => {
    Users = [
    ]
    var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
    query.once("value")
    .then((snapshot)  => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)  => {
    // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    // childData will be the actual contents of the child
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();

    getFilmDetailFromApi(childData.filmID).then(data => {
      km = this.getDistance(this.state.userData.latitude, this.state.userData.longitude, childData.latitude, childData.longitude)
      photo0 = null;
      photo1 = null;
      photo2 = null;
      photo3 = null;
      photo4 = null;
      photo5 = null;
      if(childData.photo[0]) {
        photo0 = {uri: childData.photo[0]}
      }
      if(childData.photo[1]) {
        photo1 = {uri: childData.photo[1]}
      }
      if(childData.photo[2]) {
        photo2 = {uri: childData.photo[2]}
      }
      if(childData.photo[3]) {
        photo3 = {uri: childData.photo[3]}
      }
      if(childData.photo[4]) {
        photo4 = {uri: childData.photo[4]}
      }
      if(childData.photo[5]) {
        photo5 = {uri: childData.photo[5]}
      }
      var filmImage = data.poster_path
      Users.push({ id: key, uri: photo0, uri1: photo1, uri2: photo2, uri3: photo3, uri4: photo4, uri5: photo5, nom: childData.name, age:childData.age, film: filmImage, description: childData.description, distance: km })
      this.setState({ users: key });
    })
    this.setState({Users: Users});
    });
    this.setState({isLoading: false});
    this.setState({currentIndex: 0});
  });   
  }
```

This work like the tinder cards, when i swipe them all (this.state.Users.length == this.state.currentIndex) become true and it render the loading screen and from there i want to re-run the loadUsers function to get new users but when i run the app i get : "Maximum update depth exceeded".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoadUsers loads user and sets the state, which causes a rerender of loading screen. Then the loading screen run the LoadUser again trigers the flow again.

Edit1:
**At least**, you'd have to have some logic to update the status of loading:

Check the modified code:

```
loadUsers = () => {
    Users = [
    ]
    var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
    query.once("value")
    .then((snapshot)  => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)  => {
    // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    // childData will be the actual contents of the child
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();

    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    getFilmDetailFromApi(childData.filmID).then(data => {
    km = this.getDistance(this.state.userData.latitude, this.state.userData.longitude, childData.latitude, childData.longitude)
    photo0 = null;
    photo1 = null;
    photo2 = null;
    photo3 = null;
    photo4 = null;
    photo5 = null;
    if(childData.photo[0]) {
        photo0 = {uri: childData.photo[0]}
    }
    if(childData.photo[1]) {
        photo1 = {uri: childData.photo[1]}
    }
    if(childData.photo[2]) {
        photo2 = {uri: childData.photo[2]}
    }
    if(childData.photo[3]) {
        photo3 = {uri: childData.photo[3]}
    }
    if(childData.photo[4]) {
        photo4 = {uri: childData.photo[4]}
    }
    if(childData.photo[5]) {
        photo5 = {uri: childData.photo[5]}
    }
    var filmImage = data.poster_path
    Users.push({ id: key, uri: photo0, uri1: photo1, uri2: photo2, uri3: photo3, uri4: photo4, uri5: photo5, nom: childData.name, age:childData.age, film: filmImage, description: childData.description, distance: km })
    this.setState({ users: key, isLoading: false });
    })
    this.setState({Users: Users});});
    this.setState({currentIndex: 0});
});   
}
```

Comment: So how should i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to set state inside a loop and the maximum limit has reached to rerender a view once there is change in state. Try to set Users `this.setState({ Users: Users });` once the foreach loop ends(outside of loop). `this.setState({ users: key });` this may also need the similar approach.